# How to make text fit in UITableViewCell is iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UILabelCell but don't know how to make all the text in that label fit (sometimes it overruns). Any ideas of how I could resize the text in iOS7 (all the solutions are for previous OS'es that don't work with iOS7 because the methods are deprecated...)

Here is the code for making the cell:

```
if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.textLabel.text = text;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean allow the text to overflow onto multiple lines? You can use the `numberOfLines` property which is 1 by default.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

0 signifies an unlimited number of lines.

The caveat is you'll also need to provide a taller height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if there are too many lines to fit in whatever height you're using (or the default height).

Comment: how do I provide a taller height? Sorry, new to iOS, so this stuff is confusing...

Comment: The UITableViewDelegate has a method for that: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

(I'm assuming you want it to fit on one line in the available space.)